# Is it possible for us to merge cells in UWP DataGrid

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

We are requested to create a DataGrid which include merged cells in it. I see that syncfusion has this kind of function. Does anyone know how we can create the same based on GridView or communitytoolkit DataGrid?
Here is what it looks like in syncfusion:
https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/datagrid/merge-cells

Since we only need to merge part of rows. I'm thinking about this, maybe I can write a custom control which can be put on top of the datagrid(we don't need to edit the cell)? In that way maybe I also need to disable UI virtualization?

Comment: Hello Barry, `DataGrid` does not currently provide methods for merging cells. If you just need a single cross-row or cross-column, you can consider rendering through `ListView`, create a custom user control as a `DataTemplate`, and determine the specific display effect based on the incoming data. If you need to cross rows and columns at the same time, you may need more complex control definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` in UWP does not have the function of merging cells. But on the web, there are some more mature solutions.

You can use `WebView` in UWP to achieve your needs through web solutions.

Thanks.